# Get the current users language in static class of domain project

Tags: localization, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, static-libraries, clean-architecture

I have 2 Projects in my solution

- Api which is the runnable project and contains the api enpoints
- Domain which holds the entites and the validators (fluent validation) for them

Now I will have to return culture specific error messages from the Domain project. As the Domain Project cannot access the Api project, there is (probably) no clean way to access the database and the httpcontext, where the users language is stored.

So I decided to do the translation the old way and added a static language helper class, which holds a ResourceManager to access the resx files.

I stored the current users culture via a middleware in the api project to the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture class so it is accesible inside the languageHelper class.

But as CultureInfo is not different per request (scoped) but instead per thread, this approach will cause problems when 2 requests form different users are proccessed at the same time on the same thread.

Is there another way to get the current users langage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there seems no possibility to do this inside the library project.

Decided to solve it like this:

- Return the non-localized error messages as custom ValidationException from the Domain to the Api project and translate them there.
- Added the resx files into the Domain project, so the translated messages are the same place like the validators.
- The translation will be done inside the global error handler middleware, which lives inside the Api project. (If the error is of type ValidationError)
- To save the current users language, I introduced a CurrentUserProvider Class which will be registered as a scoped service and holds a CurrentUsersCulture property.
- The CurrentUsersCulture property will be set at every request through another custom middleware.
- Cached the languages from all users, to make shure, not every request needs to access the database to get the current users language.